# WPF: Converter for ListView event?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, converters

So i have this `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="lvFiles"
          AllowDrop="True"
          Drop="lvFiles_Drop"/>
```

And my View Model peoperty:

```
private bool _allowDrop;

public bool AllowDrop
{
    get { return _allowDrop; }
    set
    {
        _allowDrop = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

So currently i am using code behind to register/unregister this `Drop` event:

```
lvFiles.Drop -= lvFiles_Drop;
```

is it possible to write `converter` instead of doing that in code behind ?

Comment: you don't need that "lvFiles.Drop -= lvFiles_Drop;" - it's allready attached in your XAML;

Comment: @GCamel `-=` is removing, not adding.

Comment: Usually this would be a behavior rather than a converter since you want to hook events.  There are a number of helpers that encapsulate drag drop out there on the web if you do a search.  These "just" encapsulate view events and you might find it's simpler to just put code in the view's code behind if you're not going to re-use this several times. Also. For some purposes, I find drag drop is clunky and I prefer to drag a thumb instead. This is particularly true if I want a fancy object in the view as the user drags.

Comment: yes, i saw that..but why removing by code ? you can use EventToCommand ==> here a sample https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR/blob/646365a0faab8452fb847be9d66b5f1dd493530f/CBR/Views/Tools/ExplorerView.xaml